# Closest Distance Between Polygons In Shapefile With Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

very new to Geopandas, I'm loading in a shapefile into a GeoDataFrame - it's a shapefile of the US states with a Polygon or Multipolygon for each.  I'd like to calculate the minimum distance (in km or miles) between each pair of states - i.e. the closest distance from the CA polygon and the TX polygon for example (with 0 or a very small number for bordering states).

sample code of loading the gdf from shapefile (shapefile projection is GCS_North_American_1983):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

shapefile = 'states.shp'
shape_gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how you can calculate the distances, using the boroughs in ny as sample dataset:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# path = "states.shp"
path = gpd.datasets.get_path("nybb")
gdf = gpd.read_file(path)

# Geopandas needs a projected crs to get sensible distances. "USA Contiguous Equidistant Conic" is a reasonable option for USA states.
# gdf = gdf.to_crs("ESRI:102005")

result_gdf = None
for row in gdf.itertuples():
    other_gdf = gdf[gdf.index < row.Index]
    distances = other_gdf.geometry.distance(row.geometry)
    distances_gdf = other_gdf.copy()
    distances_gdf["distance"] = distances
    for name, value in row._asdict().items():
        distances_gdf[f"to_{name}"] = value

    if result_gdf is None:
        result_gdf = distances_gdf
    else:
        result_gdf = pd.concat([result_gdf, distances_gdf])

print(result_gdf[["BoroName", "to_BoroName", "distance"]].to_string(index=False))
```

Result:

```
     BoroName   to_BoroName     distance
Staten Island        Queens 30636.103288
Staten Island      Brooklyn  4895.344637
       Queens      Brooklyn     0.000000
Staten Island     Manhattan 17455.990534
       Queens     Manhattan     0.000000
     Brooklyn     Manhattan     0.000000
Staten Island         Bronx 69951.707811
       Queens         Bronx     0.000000
     Brooklyn         Bronx 23611.105964
    Manhattan         Bronx     0.000000
```

Comment: yeah but i need this to load any .shp file not a geopandas dataset.

Comment: As you have shown in the code snippet in your question, you can just pass a shapefile path to `gpd.read_file`?

Comment: edit: I avoided as much data-specific code as possible.

Comment: ok almost there - it's calculating distance however the source data is in crs 4269, which should I convert that to if the source polygons are all over the US so I can get distances in meters?

Comment: figured it out...converted to a utm crs, thanks again.